# Python, sorted(): Sorting football stats by 3rd column

Tags: python, tuples, sorting

I have football stats that are in a file. I can split the name of the player and each stat by two or more spaces. I am trying to get yards leaders so I need to sort by the 4th column or 3rd index.

Here's my code:

```
import re, sys
try:
   file = open("TTL.txt", "r")
except IOError:
   print "Could Not Open TTL"
sys.exit()
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
   line = re.split("\s\s+", line)
def key_fct(lines):
   return (float(lines[3]))
srtlines = sorted(lines, key = key_fct, reverse = True)
for line in srtlines:
   print line
file.close()
```

Sample Input:

```
abel161 8 77 443.0 5 0 11.7 147.2
Abyss ll 38 145 1158.0 11 6 12.8 55.9
AFFISHAUL 34 33 366.0 2 4 17.8 22.7
Assassin NinjaX 25 35 184.0 0 7 10.3 15.1
aubby57 23 165 839.0 11 0 10.5 75.3
B1U3 S4V10R 26 116 380.0 4 6 6.0 29.2
Bigkle 24 47 149.0 2 4 6.7 32.8
BLKSUP3RSA1YAN 5 52 65.0 3 1 9.9 22.7
Booksack 33 85 477.0 5 5 11.0 29.2
Brandon6154xx 23 106 809.0 8 0 17.6 97.0
budweizerbeast 35 472 1640.0 27 9 6.8 94.5
BulkKiller1 31 455 3012.0 40 5 12.6 182.6
Carnage311 30 369 2349.0 25 6 12.8 158.3
cinemagiic 32 12 -8.0 0 2 -1.3 -0.6
Cmfc bumble bee 20 41 253.0 1 0 12.3 28.9
CMFCplaya 19 78 366.0 4 4 9.5 48.9
```

I get two errors:

```
$./sort.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sort.py", line 39, in <module>
    srtlines = sorted(lines, key = key_fct, reverse=True)
  File "./sort.py", line 37, in key_fct
    return (float(lines[3]))  
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): l
```

My file is not a list of lists, but if I split each line and try to sort by the 3rd index, I still get the 4th character in the first name in the file.

Comment: What have you done? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: When working with files in Python, you should always use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4). You should also use [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html) here, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is, you're iterating over `lines` but assigning a new value to `line` inside the loop doesn't modify the content of original list. It is still a list of strings, so `lines[3]` actually returns the third character from each line not the third item as you expected.

```
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
   line = re.split("\s\s+", line)  #This thing won't affect original list
```

You can do:

```
lines = file.readlines()
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
   lines[i] = re.split("\s\s+", line)
```

**Or better:**

```
import re
with open('abc') as f:
    lines = [re.split("\s\s+", line) for line in f]
    lines.sort(key = lambda x: float(x[3]), reverse = True)    
    print lis
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
for line in lines:
   line = re.split("\s\s+", line)
```

You can't modify the values of a list like this - you are just assigning a new value to the variable, which is then replaced the next time the loop runs. This does nothing at all.

Instead, use a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to construct a new list:

```
lines = [re.split("\s\s+", line) for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have here is the following code:

```
for line in lines:
    line = re.split("\s\s+", line)
```

This is not reassigning line into the list, as you expect. You're not actually changing lines at all. What I'd suggest is creating a new list like this:

```
splitLines = []
for line in lines:
    splitLines.append(re.split("\s\s+", line))
```

Or use the index instead:

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = re.split("\s\s+", lines[i])
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Iteration by index is not a good idea - it's inflexible, hard to read, and slow.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issue noted by others, you also have a basic **parsing problem**: consider those rogues **Cmfc bumble bee** and **Assassin NinjaX**. If we split their data lines on whitespace, we'll end up having too many fields in the data, because the names contain whitespace. Element `[3]`, for example, won't have consistent meaning from one data record to another.

Here's a different way to handle the problem:

```
# Read the data, naively splitting on whitespace.
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh:
    football_data = [line.split() for line in fh]

# Reorganize the data.
for i, fd in enumerate(football_data):
    # stats: the last 7 elements.
    # name:  anything to the left of the stats.
    stats = [float(n) for n in fd[-7:]]
    name  = ' '.join(fd[0:-7])
    football_data[i] = [name] + stats

# Sort as needed.
football_data.sort(key = lambda fd: fd[3], reverse = True)
```

Comment: I made sure every name in the file only has once space between, and all the stats have two or more, which I think I mentioned in the question.

Comment: but wow this is so much help on splitting the names from stats. I actually wrote a different program to go through and add extra spaces between the stats >.<

Comment: When i run this code into my program, i get this:

[pereiraa1@centos-server LA]$ ./sort.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sort.py", line 7, in <module>
    stats = [float(n) for n in x[-7:]]
ValueError: empty string for float()

Comment: @user2556506 Seems like your full data file has some irregularities and/or doesn't look exactly like the sample data you showed us. Maybe you can add some debugging print statements to find the data line where the problem occurs. And that will tell you how to adjust the parsing logic. Good luck!